# Sending Data from Xbee Arduino to PC

Tags: arduino, xbee

I have an application where I am using a MCP3421 18bit ADC to read analog data. The setup is Xbee+Xbee Sheild+Arduino + MCP3421 as Transmitter.   This I am reading and transmitting to a remote xbee+arduino module with LCD. The data is displayed fine on the LCD.  however I want to receive the data on the Serial port. When i try tp Do a Serial.println(s); on the receiving code the data which i get on serial port is garbled. Would appreciate any help

Here is my Code

Transmitting

```
#include  <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
void setup(void)
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");  // just to be sure things are working
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop(void)
{

  byte address, Hi, Lo, Config;
  int ADVal;

  while(1)
  {
    address = 0x68;
    Wire.beginTransmission(address);
    Wire.write(0x88);   // config register %1000 1000
    // /RDY = 1, One Conversion, 15 samples per, PGA = X1

    Wire.endTransmission();

    delay(1);
    Wire.requestFrom((int)address, (int) 3);
    Hi = Wire.read();
    Lo = Wire.read();
    Config = Wire.read();
    Wire.endTransmission();

    ADVal = Hi;
    ADVal = ADVal * 256 + Lo;

    //  Serial.print(ADVal, DEC);
    //Serial.print("  ");
    //Serial.println(Config, DEC);
    Serial.print("<");
    Serial.print(ADVal);
    Serial.print(">");


    //lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    //lcd.print(ADVal);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    //float val = ADVal * 0.00006244087;
    //lcd.print(val,3); 
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

and this is the receiving code

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2); // initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
bool started = false;
bool ended= false;
char inData[10]; // Leave plenty of room
byte index;
float i;

//char inData[24]; // Or whatever size you need
//byte index = 0;

void setup(){
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // initialize the serial communications:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  //Serial.println(s);
  while(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    char aChar = Serial.read();
    if(aChar == '<')
    {
      // Start of packet marker read
      index = 0;
      inData[index] = '\0'; // Throw away any incomplete packet
      started = true;
      ended = false;
    }
    else if(aChar == '>')
    {
      // End of packet marker read
      ended = true;
      break; // Done reading serial data for now
    }
    else
    {
      if(index < 10) // Make sure there is room
      {
        inData[index] = aChar; // Add char to array

        index++;
        inData[index] = '\0'; // Add NULL to end

      }
    }
  }

  // When we get here, there is no more serial data to read,
  // or we have read an end-of-packet marker
  if(started && ended)
  {
    // We've seen both markers - do something with the data here
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    i = atoi (inData);
    float s = (i * 0.3051851); //multiplying with calibration factor
    float value = ( s / 1000 );

    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.print(value,3); // print value after multiplying with calibration factor to LCD

    lcd.setCursor(0,1 );
    lcd.print(i); // Print raw ADC counts as recieved from transmitter

    index = 0;
    inData[index] = '\0';
    started = false;
    ended = false;

  }
}
```

The receiving arduino do get the data through Xbee and it displays values perfectly on the LCD( Attached PIC). I also need to receive the data on a PC attached to the receiving arduino through its USB/Serial port.

When i try to use the serial monitor the display on LCD vanishes and the serial monitor displays garbled values. I thing the Serial.print(s) is sending back the data to the XBEE  as both the DO and DI LED starts blinking on the XBEE SHIELD.

Comment: You might need to post a schematic of your connections so we can understand how the XBee, LCD and serial monitor interface to the Arduino.  If any of them are sharing I/O lines on the Arduino, you will run into problems.

Comment: Sorry I cant seem to post an image here as I dont have enough points. Anyways the Xbee is mounted on and Xbee Sheild ( http://itead-europe.com/pm/platform/shield/xbee%20shield/DS_IM120417004_XBeeShield.pdf ) My LCD is connected through standard connections as this image ( http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Tutorial/LCD_bb.png)